# redirecting to another page on pressing "enter" in the search text box

Tags: jquery, html, redirect, location

i have a search text box where the text for searching is entered and on pressing "enter" key, it should redirect to another page according to the type of the text using jquery.

here is my html

```
<div class="search">
     <form role="form">
        <input type="text" id="pagesearch" class="search-form" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search"><i class="fa fa-search srch"></i>
     </form>
 </div>
```

and here is my jquery part.

```
$(document).keypress(function(event){    
                if(event.which==13){
                        //alert('enter entered');
                        $('.srch').trigger('click');
            }   
            });

            $(document).on('click','.srch',function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var search_text = $('#pagesearch').val();
                //alert(search_text);
                if(search_text == 'qbcd' || search_text == 'QBCD'){
                    //alert('qbcd searched');
                    location.href = "page1.html";
                    //$(location).attr('href','page1.html');
                }else if(search_text == 'qbickle' || search_text == 'QBICKLE'){
                    //alert('qbickle searched');
                    $(location).attr('href','page2.html');
                    //location.href = "page2.html";
                }else{
                    alert('specified content for search is unavailable');
                }
            });
```

i used `location.href`, `window.location` and `window.location.href` but i'm unable to redirect to other pages.
kindly help me.
thanks in advance.

Comment: only have to use `window.location.href="page2.html";`

Comment: i'm unable to redirect

Comment: It seems to work. In which condition it is not working.

Comment: You are submiting the form by clicking enter on input

Comment: on pressing "enter" im reading the text in the textbox in jquery and based on that i need to redirect to the respective pages. im unable to do it. but im sure that im able to read  "enter" key pressed.

Comment: So prevent form to be submited (on pressing enter). And if you want your text to be case insensitive, compare value using e.g `.toLowerCase()`

Comment: your `.srch` is on `<i>` instead of `<input>`

Comment: on clicking the `<i>`  with  `srch` is working properly. but i need to redirect by just pressing enter button after the text.

Comment: then you have to move class `.srch` to `input`

Comment: Have you done `class="search-form srch"`?

Comment: oh yeah done. Its working now. Thank you for your help Parth Trivedi and A.Wolff.